# Make a search menu disappear when the search field loses focus, but still allow user to click on links

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, onblur

[On my website](http://electricdenim.co.uk/) I have a search box (text input field).
When the user clicks on it and starts typing text a menu of links appears.
The menu appears via JQuery - The following command makes the menu appear:

```
".focus(function() {
    $("#instant_search_wrapper").show();
}); "
```

When the user clicks off the search box, I would like the menu to disappear.

The easiest way of doing this would be to be use the following command:

```
".blur(function() {
    $("#instant_search_wrapper").hide();
});"
```

However, if I do this, then when the user clicks on a link in the menu, the text input field loses focus and so the menu disappears before the user is taken to the select page.
How can I make it so the menu disappears when the search field loses focus, (but if the user clicks on a link before the search field loses focus, s/he is still able to be taken to the link)?

Comment: I have this same question, I hope you get an answer posted shortly. =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to bind the click to body for hiding

```
$(document).click(function() {
      $("#instant_search_wrapper").hide();

});
```

### See Working example at http://jsfiddle.net/WYbp3/4/

Comment: That answer is 6 years old, is it still the only solution of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specific, I don't understand the question. I checked your site and when I start typing something, a modal box style menu with the results is showed. Then if I blur the input the box still there.