# jquery: custom select box - collapse when nothing get's selected

Tags: jquery, html, css, select, drop-down-menu

hey guys,
I'm trying to build a simple custom select box with jquery.

html:

```
<div class="select">
    <ul>
        <li class="option darr">Dropdown one</li>
        <li class="option">Dropdown two</li>
        <li class="option">Dropdown three</li>
    <ul>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
$('.select ul li.option').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings().toggle().removeClass('darr');
    $(this).addClass('darr');
})
```

You can check out the working example right here: http://jsfiddle.net/WFTvq/2/

This works fine actually, however there is one little thing that bugs me.
When I click on the custom select field all options are shown. If I do not choose one of the options and click anywhere else on the window the dropdown does not collapse autamatically.

A normal select box would collapse if I click anywhere else on the screen, how could I implement that behaviour in my example?

Thank you

h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered a similar question at [Make a search menu disappear when the search field loses focus, but still allow user to click on links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197712/jquery-and-blur-make-a-search-menu-disappear-when-the-search-field-loses-focus/5197807#5197807)

You can detect when a mouse is clicked outside by doing

```
$(document).click(function(){
   ...
});
```

Full code for your example

```
$('.select ul li.option').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).siblings().toggle().removeClass('darr');
    $(this).addClass('darr');
});


$(document).click(function() {
    $('.select ul li.option').siblings().not('.darr').css('display', 'none');
});
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/WFTvq/3/